# C++ Pig latin code, just deletes file info

Tags: c++, string, data-manipulation

So I am trying to make a pig latin program, that reads from a specified file, and then turns it into pig latin. But for some reason its only clearing the original file, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    char filename[200];
    cout<< "Enter name of input file: ";
    cin.getline(filename,200);
    in.open(filename);
    string out;
    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"ERROR failed to open input file " << filename << " BYE\n";
        //this.exit();
    }
    char word[200];
    bool result;
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        in>>word;
        result=check(word);
        if(result==true)
            vowel(word);
        else
            consonant(word);
        out += word;
        out += " ";

    }
    cout << out;
}

bool check(char word[200])
{
    if(word[0]=='a'|| word[0]=='e'|| word[0]=='i'|| word[0]=='o'|| word[0]=='u'|| word[0]=='A'|| word[0]=='E'|| word[0]=='I'|| word[0]=='O'|| word[0]=='U')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void vowel (char word[])
{
    int last(0);
    last=strlen(word);
    word[last]='w';
    word[last+1]='a';
    word[last+2]='y';
    word[last+3]='\0';

}

void consonant(char word[])
{
    int last;
    char temp='\0';
    last=strlen(word);
    word[0]=temp;
    for(int i=1;i<last-1;i++)
    {
        char tem=word[i];
        word[i]=word[i+1];
        word[i-1]=tem;
    }
    word[last-1]=temp;
    word[last]='a';
    word[last+1]='y';
    word[last+2]='\0';
}
```

I included the following:

- iostream
- fstream
- cstring

I apologize for all the code, but I really have no idea where my code is wrong, so I included everything.

I am trying to do this on a windows 8 computer, and this may be part of the cause.

My output is also either blank or just a pointer...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code, the original input file is still OK.

And for the input file data: `avoid pig`, output is `avoidway ig`, is this result you want?

For some kind of pig Latin, for consonant people will move the first char to the end and add `ay` to the word?
If it is right, you can try this code:

```
void consonant(char word[])
{
    int last = strlen(word);
    char temp = word[0];
    for(int i=0; i<last-1; ++i)
    {
        word[i]=word[i+1];
    }
    word[last-1]=temp;
    word[last]='a';
    word[last+1]='y';
    word[last+2]='\0';
}
```